# Multi-Sign Withdraw payment

Tags: stellar-sdk

How do you withdraw funds from a multi-sig account?

Answer (score 2):

The operation to withdraw is a payment.

In order to make a payment from an account, the transaction must be signed with sufficient signers to meet the threshold for a medium security operation.

Every account can set different levels for high, medium and low operations. And each signer has a weight. The weight of all signers must exceed the threshold for the operations attempted.

[See the docs for a better worded explanation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#thresholds).

Comment: I don't have idea about withdrway payment using Stelalr SDK. Do you have any document link or something which I can refer. It would be great help if you will provide.

Comment: You should start with https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/ . Follow that through and you'll be making payments on the test network in no time.